# Change in data type from bigint to double while renaming in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python Pandas. I am having data input in the below form.

```
Name,Empid,2020_salary,2021_salary,2022_salary
Adam,21223,58000,60000,62000
John,21534,67465,70985,90857
Terry,35463,76000,86765,97886
```

As you observe in the year I am getting an underscore salary(ex 2020_salary) along with the year. But I want the data in the below form

```
    Name,Empid,2020,2021,2022
    Adam,21223,58000,60000,62000
    John,21534,67465,70985,90857
    Terry,35463,76000,86765,97886
```

Since the table structure is not consistent(New Year will add in the future). That's why I cannot manually rename each column. I used pandas to rename all columns having salary text in the column.

```
df.rename(columns= lambda x: x.replace('_salary',''),inplace=True)
```

Now I got the column structure the way I wanted. But now my data type has been changed from int to
double for some columns.

```
        Name,Empid,2020,2021,2022
        Adam,21223,58000.0,60000,62000
        John,21534,67465.0,70985,90857
        Terry,35463,76000.0,86765,97886
```

I am getting output similar to the above. Can you please help me how to convert the above double data type to int without manually changing anything or some better way to rename the year's column?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_salary', '')` instead of `.rename`.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Use `pd.__version__`. Works find on mine (1.4.2)

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]